# Compare a date in string format with todays date

Tags: javascript

I know this has been asked before but I can't get it to work due to my date format, which I can't change. Any help would be appreciated.

My date is in this format;

`4/11/2017 12:30 PM`.

If I inspect it in the developer tools it shows it as

`4/11/2017 12:30 PM` EDIT: Won't show with prepended space here

i.e. with a space in front, not sure if that's relevant.

Does anyone know if it's possible or how to compare it with today's date to see if it's in the past or future?

I've tried tinkering with the following code but can't get it to work because of the time, PM, and forward slashes.

```
var q = new Date();
var m = q.getMonth();
var d = q.getDate();
var y = q.getFullYear();

var date = new Date(d,m,y);

mydate=new Date('13/04/2017');
console.log(date);
console.log(mydate)

if(date>mydate)
{
    alert("greater");
}
else
{
    alert("smaller")
}
```

Comment: https://momentjs.com/

Comment: Be careful, `date` is not well formed, as it should have been created as `Date(y,m,d)`, and the `mydate` variable is a not valid Date. You can always check the date created is correct by using the `date.toString()` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have dates that are in the same format of something like `13/04/2017`, you could `split` the string based on the slashes and compare the values starting from the right moving left.

By this, I mean when you have your array of three values for each date, you could first compare the year, if that's the same, move on to comparing the month, if that's the same then on to comparing the day.

But if for instance one of the year's is `2018` while the other is `2016`, you would immediately know that the `2018` one comes later.

```
var st = "19/05/2019";
var st2 = "19/05/2019";

function provideLaterDate(date1, date2) {
    var splitDateDate1 = date1.split("/").reverse();
    var splitDateDate2 = date2.split("/").reverse();
    var laterDate = false;

    splitDateDate1.forEach(function(val, idx, arr) {
        if ( laterDate === false ) {
            if ( val > splitDateDate2[idx] ) {

                laterDate = splitDateDate1;
            } else if ( val < splitDateDate2[idx]) {

                laterDate = splitDateDate2;

            } else {
                laterDate = "Both are the same";
            }
        }
    });

    if ( /\//.test(laterDate) ) {
        return laterDate.reverse().join("/");    
    } else {
        return laterDate;
    }

}
```

To get rid of the "time pm" part, you could simply do something like:

```
// Assuming your date has a structure like this: 4/11/2017 12:30 PM.

var newDate = unformattedDate.split(" ")[0];

// This will separate your date string by spaces, and since there are no spaces until after the year in your date, the 0 index will give you the date minus the time and pm portion. Please pardon the not-consistent variable names.
```

Comment: Thanks for answering, do you know how to get rid of the time and PM bit? Just split the date again but by space characters?

Comment: Sure. Updated the post.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with the way you were constructing date. Construct date like this `var mydate = new Date(2017, 04, 03);` and it works.

```
var q = new Date();
var m = q.getMonth();
var d = q.getDate();
var y = q.getFullYear();

var date = new Date(d, m, y);

var mydate = new Date(2017, 04, 03);
console.log(date);
console.log(mydate)

if (date > mydate) {
  alert("greater");
}
else {
  alert("smaller")
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the date. Be aware you should contruct your date as follows:

```
var date = new Date(y,m,d);
```

Means year first, then month and finally day, as you can see under https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

You can use the following code to perform what you want:

```
var q = new Date();
var m = q.getMonth();
var d = q.getDate();
var y = q.getFullYear();

var date = new Date(y,m,d);

newdate = '13/04/2017'
array = newdate.split('/');
var d1 = array[0]
var m1 = array[1]-1
var y1 = array[2]

mydate = new Date(y1,m1,d1);
console.log(date);
console.log(mydate)

if(date>mydate)
{
    alert("greater");
}
else
{
    alert("smaller")
}
```

You can always check the date created is correct by using the `date.toString()` function. Be aware 0=January for month as you can check under https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_getmonth.asp. That's why I added the -1 for var m1.

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**

It's not working because you are comparing a date with an `Invalid date`, it will always return `false`.

**Explanation:**

And the `Invalid date` comes from the line `new Date('13/04/2017')`, because `13` is expected to be a `month` number and not a `day` which is an invalid month, because the `new Date(stringDate)` will be treated as a local Date and not a UTC date by the browser, and it depends on which browser you are using.

You can see in the [**JavaScript Date Specification**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) that:

> parsing of date strings with the Date constructor (and Date.parse, they are equivalent) is strongly discouraged due to browser differences and inconsistencies. Support for RFC 2822 format strings is by convention only. Support for ISO 8601 formats differs in that date-only strings (e.g. "1970-01-01") are treated as UTC, not local.

**Demo:**

So if we change `new Date('13/04/2017')` to `new Date('04/13/2017')` the code will work as expected:

```js
var date = new Date();

var mydate = new Date('04/13/2017');
console.log(date);
console.log(mydate)

if (date > mydate) {
  alert("greater");
} else {
  alert("smaller")
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
if(date.getTime()>mydate.getTime()){
alert("greater");
}
else if (date.getTime()==mydate.getTime){
alert("simmilar");
else {alert("smaller");}
```

Comment: This code would not work as from the code provided in the question date was not well formed, as it should have been created as Date(y,m,d), and the mydate variable was a not valid Date.